# Naming convention of v-model for Vuejs and Axios in a POST request (Issues encoding a Vue Object into JSON)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

this is going to be super long winded!

Admittedly I am not a good frontend designer and my Javascript skills leave much to be improved upon.

**TL:DR** - How is the working code different from the JSON encoded data object (merchant) in the non-working code, in regards to the Axios POST request? Shouldn't they produce the same result?

Some background first: I am building a Laravel REST backend that is feature complete, form validators, policies, the works. I have tested the backend with the ARC REST client for Chrome and have verified my backend is fully functional.

The problem: While designing my frontend using Vuejs, Vue-Router and Axios, I am having issues POSTing data to my backend. Specifically it is failing form validation with an HTTP error 422. I have narrowed down this issue to be relating to object encapsulation in either Vue or Axios.

Here is the **non-working** Vue component:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Create Merchant</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="#" @submit.prevent="createMerchant()">
                Primary
                <input v-model="merchant.primary" type="text" name="primary" class="form-control" autofocus>
                Alternate
                <input v-model="merchant.alternate" type="text" name="alternate" class="form-control">
                Contact
                <input v-model="merchant.contact" type="text" name="contact" class="form-control">
                Street
                <input v-model="merchant.street" type="text" name="street" class="form-control">
                City
                <input v-model="merchant.city" type="text" name="city" class="form-control">
                State
                <input v-model="merchant.state" type="text" name="state" class="form-control">
                Country
                <input v-model="merchant.country" type="text" name="country" class="form-control">
                Postal Code
                <input v-model="merchant.postalCode" type="text" name="postalCode" class="form-control">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Merchant</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div v-if='errors && errors.length' class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Error</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
                <li v-for='error of errors'>
                    {{error.message}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            merchant: {
                primary: '',
                alternate: '',
                contact: '',
                street: '',
                city: '',
                state: '',
                country: '',
                postalCode: ''
            },
            errors: []
        };
    },

    methods: {
        createMerchant() { console.log(JSON.stringify(this.merchant));
            axios.post('/payment-gateway/public/api/v1/merchant', JSON.stringify(this.merchant))
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.id);
                this.$router.push({ name: 'merchantList' });
            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e);
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The data being posted, from my point of view appears to be correct:

> {"primary":"Widget Company","alternate":"Widget Co","contact":"555-555-0055","street":"123 Main St","city":"Olympia","state":"WA","country":"USA","postalCode":"98501"}

But the above code always results in a HTTP 422 error.

Now for the part that is confusing me, this is **working** code:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Create Merchant</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="#" @submit.prevent="createMerchant()">
                Primary
                <input v-model="merchant.primary" type="text" name="primary" class="form-control" autofocus>
                Alternate
                <input v-model="merchant.alternate" type="text" name="alternate" class="form-control">
                Contact
                <input v-model="merchant.contact" type="text" name="contact" class="form-control">
                Street
                <input v-model="merchant.street" type="text" name="street" class="form-control">
                City
                <input v-model="merchant.city" type="text" name="city" class="form-control">
                State
                <input v-model="merchant.state" type="text" name="state" class="form-control">
                Country
                <input v-model="merchant.country" type="text" name="country" class="form-control">
                Postal Code
                <input v-model="merchant.postalCode" type="text" name="postalCode" class="form-control">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Merchant</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div v-if='errors && errors.length' class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Error</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
                <li v-for='error of errors'>
                    {{error.message}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            merchant: {
                primary: '',
                alternate: '',
                contact: '',
                street: '',
                city: '',
                state: '',
                country: '',
                postalCode: ''
            },
            errors: []
        };
    },

    methods: {
        createMerchant() { console.log(JSON.stringify(this.merchant));
            axios.post('/payment-gateway/public/api/v1/merchant', {
                primary: this.merchant.primary,
                alternate: this.merchant.alternate,
                contact: this.merchant.contact,
                street: this.merchant.street,
                city: this.merchant.city,
                state: this.merchant.state,
                country: this.merchant.country,
                postalCode: this.merchant.postalCode
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.id);
                this.$router.push({ name: 'merchantList' });
            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e);
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

So my question is, how is the working code different from the JSON encoded data object (merchant) in the non-working code?

Comment: One your sending an object, the other a string. I would imagine you'd need to do something with the ContentType of the first to tell it the data is in JSON format.

Comment: Thank you for your input! Wouldn't the object be converted into a string when it is serialized by JSON.stringify()? I will have to check the encoding type, I think I may have left it at 'application/x-www-urlencoded' which might also be screwing me up (doh!)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the reply :) The object would of course be translated into a string but as it's doing it I would also imagine it's setting the ContentType to `application/json`. Let me know how your testing goes and I'll add an answer if this is the issue. Don't wan to add one yet as I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Setting the content type to JSON was the golden ticket! Now I can pass a serialized object to my post functions and it works like a charm. Cheers!

Would have responded sooner but the Stack overflow app has a habit of not sending notifications.

Comment: Great to hear. Have added an answer for the next bod that runs into the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one instance you're sending an object, in the other a string. Although they will both be transferred as a string eventually, when you pass the object, the `ContentType` is set under the hood to `application/json`.

That being said, if you set the `ContentType` to `application/json` for the one you're passing as a string, it will sort the issue.